# How do I make a background-image larger with a @media query?

Tags: html, css, background, media-queries, size

I'd simply like my background image to become larger when I increase my viewport size to @media only screen /* Tablet */ and (min-width: 768px) {}.

I've tried background-size:; however that didn't work.

I then tried to use a different image file to apply the background-size:; too and still nothing.

How would I go about doing this?

HTML:

```
    <advert class="bg-righttoleft">
      <div class="title-shift">
        <h1 class="title text-style">bla bla bla</h1>
        <h3 class="title-shift-h3 text-style">bla bla bla</h3>
        <p class="title-shift-p">bla bla bla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="channel">
        <h3 class="chan-text">Review of the week</h3>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-6OW5aJYBFM33zXQlBKPNA">
        <img class="chan-img" src="./engadget.jpg" alt="Engadget logo"></a>
      </div>
    </advert>
```

CSS:

```
.container  {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "advert"
    "main"
    "footer";
  text-align: center;
}

advert  {
  grid-area: advert;
  background: url(./mi-vr-5.jpg);
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: 75%;
  background-size: 1000px;
}

@media only screen /* Tablet */
  and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container  {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
      grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "advert"
      "main"
      "footer";
    }

    advert  {
      background: url(./mi-vr-5-tablet.jpg);
      background-size: 2000px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a missing `}` at the end

Comment: At the end of what?!

Comment: of your CSS code, follow the `{` `}` and you will see a opened without a closed one

Comment: This is just a brief copy of the CSS. If I’m missing a } at the end it’s because there’s more content I have chosen not to include because it’s not relevant. Rest assured I have closed my media query

Comment: even if you ommit a part of the code you should include a relevant and **correct** code. It's not because your code is too long that you cut in the middle. We will simply consider this as broken and the question may simply get closed

Comment: Well it’s quite obvious what I’m saying and closing the question because the media query is not closed is rather petty. The fact that the media query is not closed has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: a broken code will not work so we can conclude that this is the issue and it's not *petty* because we are not mind reader to know that you correctly wrote your code. We judge what we see.

Comment: in addition to all this your code also lack an MCVE, this is also a reason for a question being closed. You should at least inlcude the image so we can see it's not getting changed with the media query and you should make a running snippet also.

Comment: I’m obviously still learning. How is what you’re doing helping me? Surely this directly contradicts what this website is for? You’re not helping me at all. You’re stopping me. Also are you telling me you don’t understand what I’m asking because I think it’s quite obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to scale up your background image you can use:

**background-size: width height;**

for example:

**background-size: 200% auto;**

> Temani Afif also meant that the closing tag "}" of @media only screen /* Tablet */
>     and (min-width: 768px) is missing

Here is my sample code:

```
<div class="background"></div>

.background{
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1735092/pexels-photo-1735092.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 1000px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: @Maximilian stop accusing people that are trying to help you ;) as a side note background size works fine if you define it with only one value which is what you already done, so you question still don't show an issue : https://jsfiddle.net/vwm36zen/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I discovered my error. In my class connected to my @keyframes I had specified background-size again. I’ve now deleted it from my advert class as it seemed cleaner to leave the background-size in my animation class. Perfect! Also Temani I do appreciate the help.